# What exactly does Apple documentation mean by "scene support"?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscene

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle

> Scene support is an opt-in feature

> Apps must explicitly opt in to scenes, which you do by updating your app’s configuration settings.

> In iOS 12 and earlier, and in apps that don't support scenes, UIKit delivers all life-cycle events to the UIApplicationDelegate object.

However, apps by default, which aren't opted in, have a scene delegate and receive all life-cycle event reporting through the scene delegate (not the app delegate). This contradicts Apple's documentation, which wouldn't be the first time. Shouldn't the documentation instead state that *multiple-scene support* is an opt-in feature?

Comment: If you have a scene delegate then you have opted into scene support

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking the documentation to be too pedantic.

If you create a delegate to handle scenes then you have "opted in" to scene support.  The question of whether or not you can create multiple scenes is a related, but orthogonal question.

Even an iPhone that has a scene delegate can receive scene messages, but it cannot create multiple scenes.